# Android Studio Cross Platform

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I have 3 devices (Not including phones). 1 Desktop, 1 Laptop and 1 Tablet all of which is running on Intel x86_64 CPU's. The Desktop and Laptop has Fedora installed while the Tablet, being a non-linux supported BayTrail, has Window 8.1. I mostly work on the Desktop and Laptop, but some times the Tablet is used for smaller things. I have Android Studio installed on all 3 devices using Copy.com to sync up all of the work, backed by git.

Most of this is working fine, but there is a small problem. The Desktop and Laptop is easy to get to work together since I use the exact same file system layout on both. But the Tablet, running on Windows, is another thing. Android Studio saves the SDK path in the file local.properties for each project. Since the project dirs resides within the Copy.com folder, all changes are synced between all 3 devices. This creates problem since the SDK path differs between the Linux devices and the Windows Tablet. Every time I switch between the OS's, this path needs updating.

Is there a way to make this path a global Android Studio configuration that is not stored in the project dirs?

Answer (score 0):

This is the comment that Android Studio includes in the generated `local.properties` file:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
```

So, don't add this to your `git repo`. You can add the line `/local.properties` to  .`gitignore` file to that git will not sync it with the repository.

Comment: I have not added this to git, this is getting synced via Copy.com. I don't use git to sync between each device, I use git to push finished work to github, but current working progress is being kept in sync across device via Copy.com (Dropbox like service) just like all the rest of my data. I like to have all of my devices in constant sync. The SDK is a global installation and should not be configured per project, so having this in a project settings file makes no sense. Project files should only contain project related data, not IDE related data.